# Show that if $P=NP$ then there is an algorithm that finds a witness for the language $L = \{x | \exists_w M(x,w)=1 \}$

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, turing-machines, np

Let $M(x,w)$ be a polynomial Turing machine with $|w| = poly(|x|)$, and $L = \{x | \exists_w M(x,w)=1 \}$.

Assuming that $P=NP$ I want to show that there is a polynomial algorithm $N(x)$ that finds a witness for $x$ according to $L$. Namely:

$\forall_{x \in L}M(x, N(x)) = 1 $

My idea was to decide the bits of a witness $w$ using checks with the machine $M$
My attempt looks like this, on input $x \in \{0,1\}^*$, $N$ does:

1. since $L \in NP=P$, run the polynomial machine that decides $L$ to check if $x \in L$. If not, reject.
2. check if there exists $w$ such that $M(x,w) = 1$ and $w_1 = 0$. If there is, keep $w_1=0$, else set $w_1 = 1$
3. check if there exists $w$ such that $M(x,w) = 1$ and $w_2 = 0$ (with the $w_1$ from the previuos check), and do the same.
4. continue like that until all bits of $w$ are set.

However there are 2 things that I can't figure out.

First, the machine that decides $L$ only checks if $x \in L$, I can't set specific bits for the witness. So how can I force it to have specific bit for the witness. In the case of $SAT$ it is easy because I can just replace variables with constants, but in this general langugae i don't see how.

Secondly, I am not sure that I am using the assumption that $P=NP$ enough.

Help would be appreciated.